# Angular $routeProvider http://localhost/thisapp/ == ok, http://localhost/thisapp/#/ == error. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I'm having (albeit minor) issues with `$routeProvider`.

http://localhost/thisapp/ works fine, and redirects to the `.otherwise()` perfectly. But it seems that once the app is loaded and lands on the "home" url (http://localhost/thisapp/#/)

Then it breaks.

If I navigate to http://localhost/thisapp the `$location` resolves to http://localhost/thisapp/#/

If I refresh (because you know a user will do that), then the code breaks

I've tried using `$locationProvider` but that's even more confusing. It seems the more I read up on it, the more confused I get because what's documented doesn't seem to work. (If I uncomment the `$locationProvider` line below, nothing generates). I've looked at various tutorials and issues on StackOverflow, but doesn't work as it seems to be supposed to.

Here's my config code:

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // commented cuz it's not working 
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app2/components/templates/overview.html',
            controller: 'overviewController'
        })
        .when('/all_overview', {
            templateUrl: 'app2/components/templates/overview.html',
            controller: 'overviewController'
        })
        .when('/all_procurement', {
            templateUrl: 'app2/components/templates/procurement.html',
            controller: 'procurementController'
        })
        .when('/all_social', {
            templateUrl: 'app2/components/templates/social.html',
            controller: 'socialController'
        })
        .when('/all_strengthening', {
            templateUrl: 'app2/components/templates/strengthening.html',
            controller: 'strengtheningController'
        })
        .when('/all_sales', {
            templateUrl: 'app2/components/templates/sales.html',
            controller: 'salesController'
        })

        // otherwise go to all_overview
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/all_overview'
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting an error in your console?  How does it exactly break?

Comment: is this issue persistent across all browsers?

Comment: remove this. .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app2/components/templates/overview.html',
        controller: 'overviewController'
    })

Comment: Turned out I had set up a variable based on the $location, and when there was no information after the /#/ it of course threw an error. However, the answers directly above this comment, and the one below was also helpful! I'll work on the app more to see whether I can get the pretty urls I want from $locationprovider and report back.

Comment: Among other things, it was breaking links, because the <base> tag was needed (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the default routing behavior (`#`) and trying to enable html5 routing is causing you issues. Despite your attempt to `.html5Mode(true)`, newer versions of AngularJS have a notion of a `<base href />` and require additional steps to work.

> Before Angular 1.3 we didn't have this hard requirement and it was
>   easy to write apps that worked when deployed in the root context but
>   were broken when moved to a sub-context because in the sub-context all
>   absolute urls would resolve to the root context of the app. To prevent
>   this, use relative URLs throughout your app

To address what it meant by relative URLs, here is a quick example...

```
<!-- wrong: -->
<a href="/userProfile">User Profile</a>


<!-- correct: -->
<a href="userProfile">User Profile</a>
```

---

So, when you say "nothing generates" (white screen I guess?), inspect your browser console and you'll discover the following error

> Uncaught Error: [$location:nobase]

There are a couple of ways to solve this. You can include a notion of a `<base href />` in your app in the following way

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true
});
```

---

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <base href="/">
    </head>
    ...
```

or you can disregard this `<base>` tag and modify your configuration with the following

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

For more information on the topic, see the Angular Docs

[Error: $location:nobase
$location in HTML5 mode requires a tag to be present!](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)